# What does @() mean in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I've seen this a few times in Powershell, and was curious what it meant :

```
@()
```

For example, in this block :

```
    [datetime]$StartDate = ([datetime]::now.ToShortDateString())
    $TodaysMail = @()
```

thanks !

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx

Comment: @() array, not to confuse with curly braces: @{} which is dictionary/hashtable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965510/what-is-meaning-in-powershell

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `@` indicates an array. `@()` simply creates an empty array. I.e. this snippet:

```
$TodaysMail = @()
```

Would yield a variable `TodaysMail` representing an empty array.

Comment: There's a slight inaccuracy here. `@` by itself does not mean "array"; rather, `@(` opens an array subexpression and then `)` closes it, with the side effect that an empty subexpression creates, of course, an empty array.

Comment: Hi Alex , I have a new question about PS . Maybe you might be able to help ? thanks !!!

Comment: @() an empty Object[] array. If we plan to put integers, for instance: [int[]] $intA = @()  Check the question comment/link from Etan Reisner.