# What is '@{}' meaning in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have line of scripts for review here, I noticed variable declaration with a value:

```
function readConfig {
    Param([string]$fileName)
    $config = @{}
    Get-Content $fileName | Where-Object {
        $_ -like '*=*'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $config[$key] = $value
    }
    return $config
}
```

I wonder what `@{}` means in `$config = @{}`?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-creating-an-empty-hash-table/

Comment: Since you have edited the code the answer would be `Just an empty hash declararion` .

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`@{}` in PowerShell defines a hashtable, a data structure for mapping unique keys to values (in other languages this data structure is called "dictionary" or "associative array").

`@{}` on its own defines an empty hashtable, that can then be filled with values, e.g. like this:

```
$h = @{}
$h['a'] = 'foo'
$h['b'] = 'bar'
```

Hashtables can also be defined with their content already present:

```
$h = @{
    'a' = 'foo'
    'b' = 'bar'
}
```

Note, however, that when you see similar notation in PowerShell *output*, e.g. like this:

```
abc: 23
def: @{"a"="foo";"b"="bar"}
```

that is usually *not* a hashtable, but the string representation of a custom object.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, it helps a lot on my review.

Comment: is the structure of a `hashtable` (which you have said is also known as `dictionary` or `associative array` in other languages) the same as a JavaScript `object`, eg `let myObject = { "a": "foo", "b": "bar" }`?

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the `@{}`
can be seen in diffrent ways.

If the `@{}` is empty, an empty hash table is defined.

But if there is something between the curly brackets it can be used in a contex of an splatting operation.

- Hash Table
- Splatting

I think there is no need in explaining what an hash table is.

Splatting is a method of passing a collection of parameter values to a command as unit.

```
$prints = @{
    Name = "John Doe"
    Age = 18
    Haircolor = "Red"
}

Write-Host @prints
```

Hope it helps! BR

Edit:

Regarding the updated code from the questioner the answer is

It defines an **empty hash table**.

Comment: `@` can be either defining a hashtable (when followed by a list of key=value pairs in curly brackets) or do a splatting operation. `@{}` with the curly brackets defines a hashtable.

Comment: That indeed is true. Never the less I wasn't sure how the ```@{}``` was used in the original context or if the Questioner left inner part away. Thats why I also provided the Splatting option.

Comment: `@{}` without content defines an empty hashtable. Still nothing to do with splatting.

Answer (score -2):

Be aware that Get-Content has its own parameters!

THE MOST IMPORTANT 1:

[-Raw]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It would be better to place this as a comment on one of the answers that uses `Get-Content`.

Comment: Agreed. Will do that next time.